# using 32 bit installshield for packaging 64 bit binaries

Tags: windows, x86, 64-bit, installshield

iam using 32 bit installshield to package 64 bit binaries. everything works fine but default location is pointing to `c:\program files(x86)\companyname\productname`. even though i've selected 64bit at every possible place, somehow it is defaulting to x86 programfiles folder. Any kind of help would be appreciated...

Comment: Maybe he is using some kind of compression?-)

Comment: :( i want solution...not correction
for my typo i will write an imposition...

Answer (score 0):

someone [solved this issue](http://community.installshield.com/showthread.php?t=189842#post444641) by using `[ProgramFilesFolder]\..\Program Files\companyname\productname`. won't work for localized paths, though.

see also [Installing files to x64 “Program Files” from x86 msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497754/installing-files-to-x64-program-files-from-x86-msi).

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've seen that and tried. but some how it is failing with "error 1324: invalid chars in path", it says that ..\ is a invalid path :(